# Why my PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice.before is not called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement my own authorization mechanism into Spring by introducing a `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice`. Here is my code:

My SecurityContext:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.security_test"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityContext extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
{
    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager()
    {
        try {
            AffirmativeBased ab = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();
            List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> advs = ab.getDecisionVoters();
            List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
            for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : advs) {
                if (adv instanceof PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter) {
                    toBeRemoved.add(adv);
                }
            }
            for (AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object> adv : toBeRemoved) {
                advs.remove(adv);
            }
            advs.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(new MyPreInvocationAdvice()));
            return ab;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            ArrayList decisionVoters = new ArrayList();
            decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(new MyPreInvocationAdvice()));
            return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
        }
    }
}
```

My SecurityAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

And finally MyPreInvocationAdvice

```
public class MyPreInvocationAdvice implements PreInvocationAuthorizationAdvice
{
    public MyPreInvocationAdvice()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean before(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation methodInvocation, PreInvocationAttribute preInvocationAttribute)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

At this moment I'm authorizing all requests. But the thing is that the `before` method is not called at all when I make a request. Can someone please tell me where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself and just so I can refer to it myself in the future, here it goes.

Your controllers need to be annotated by `@PreAuthorize("")`. The String value does not matter if you don't want to use it later on yourself (it will be your code using it, so if you don't want to use it just discard it).

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("")
public class Controller
{
}
```